# NodeJS callback variable assignation is always one update behind

Tags: node.js, asynccallback

I'm learning NodeJS and I have the following code:

```
     var test = '';

    function test2(name,callback) {
     UserData
          .findOne({'token': name})
          .then(function(user) {
            test = user.token;
            console.log('current: '+user.token);
              return callback(user.token);
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          });
    }


var isAuthenticated = function(req,res,next){

  test2(req.cookies.remember_me, function(user) {test=user; });
console.log('test:::: '+test);
  var isLog = false;
  if(req.session.user!= undefined && req.session.user===test){
    isLog=true;

  }
  if(req.cookies.remember_me ===test){
    console.log('test'+test);
    isLog=true;

  }

  if(isLog){
     return 1;

  }else
    {
      console.log('not auth');
      return -1;
    }
}
```

and the result is :

test:::: P9Ysq2oSCHy1RVyWsePxJhpEYLD81qOiIayTyiNJCnOkmllvEspwrDAW8tD9rmfJ

not auth

current: k8LJcCty6568QpXNS3urBedlJ0MDfEYlbOqo9Q7tQi9EOyeSkyesgHHzUjBhDgZx

I know it's bcause if the async nature of NodeJS but how can i make test to be always the same as 'current';

Thank you.

Comment: You can start with indenting your code properly. By now there are tools that can do it for you, there is no reason whatsoever to have code that is this messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a pretty classic mistake of expecting code to run in the order written, but it doesn't because of the async nature of javascript. For example:

```
test2(req.cookies.remember_me, function(user) {test=user; });
console.log('test:::: '+test);
```

Here your `console.log()` will run before the callback because the callback only happens after you've heard back from the DB. (Although it's not clear where that test value ('P9Ysq2oSCH...') is coming from.

As long as you're learning Node, you should start by trying to avoiding mixing callbacks and promises. Your `findOne()` function returns a promise, which is why you can call `then()` on it. You should just return this promise and then call `then()` in the calling function:

```
function test2(name) {
    // return is important - you're returning the promise which you will use later.
    return UserData.findOne({'token': name})
        .then(function(user) {
            return user.token;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }


function isAuthenticated(req,res,next){
    return test2(req.cookies.remember_me)
    .then(function(token) {
        console.log('test:::: '+token);
        var isLog = false;
        if(req.session.user!= undefined && req.session.user===token){
            isLog=true;
        }
        if(req.cookies.remember_me ===token){
            isLog=true;
        }
        return isLog
    })     
}

// Use the function 
isAuthenticated(req,res,next)
.then(function(isLoggedin){
    if(isLoggedin) {
        // user logged in
    } else {
        // not logged in
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 1.There is no initial value of test, token values at generated and saved at login.(I reloaded multiple times thats why test had x value) 2. I need 'isAuthenticated' variable to return something like: -1 for 'not ok' and 1  for 'ok' if remember_me values matches token. Also(important) I need multiple calls on 'test2' (preferably) in the same function. I liked NodeJS before...this. Also a naive workaround : https://pastebin.com/WjnAxHHu  Lesson of today: don't try to learn NodeJS in 12 hours straight  hahaha.

Comment: You can't avoid the async issues — there's just no way around them. So you have to embrace them. What this means is that you can't expect a function that depends on async data to just return a value. It needs to return are promise or fire a callback. It really does become easy once you're used to it. I updated the answer to show a possible way of using this. I'm not sure how you will use test2 for multiple calls, so I'm not sure how to advise on that. Generally when you need to make many async calls together you use Promise.all().